# Rewriting two coupled linear matrix equations as a single linear matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The two coupled matrix equations I have are
$$Y_1 = X_1 + AX_1A^T + BX_2B^T$$
$$Y_2 = X_2 + CX_1C^T + DX_2D^T$$

I would like to write them as a single $2 \times 2$ matrix equation where each matrix element consists of the previous matrices.

For example a simpler version of this problem that I can solve is
$$Y_1 = X_1 + AX_1 + BX_2$$
$$Y_2 = X_2 + CX_1 + DX_2$$
which can be rewritten as
$$Y = (I+M)X$$
where
$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} Y_1 & 0 \\ 0 & Y_2 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad M = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}, \qquad X = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 & 0 \\ 0 & X_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $I$ is the identity matrix.

EDIT:
I don't think the solution to the simple example that I gave is correct. The $X$ and $Y$ in that case should be
$$X = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations can be put together as

$$Y=X+M_0XM_0^T+M_1XM_1^T$$ where the matrices $X$ and $Y$ have been defined in the question and

$$M_0=\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & D\end{bmatrix}\ \mathrm{and}\ M_1=\begin{bmatrix}0 & B\\C & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I don't think this is correct. It doesn't expand to the first two equations given in the OP. You get an extra two equations that are $0 = AX_1C^T + BX_2D^T$ and $0=CX_1A^T + DX_2B^T$.

Comment: @AlexeiCiobanu Sorry, I was apparently not very awake. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Yeah it looks correct now. Splitting the $M$ into $M_0$ and $M_1$ was a good idea. You can also rewrite the solution as $Y = X + M X M^T - M_0 X M_1^T - M_1 X M_0^T$, but yours is more compact. Never really appreciated before how matrix products can be split this way.

Comment: @AlexeiCiobanu This is because $M=M_0+M_1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}$You could define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
x_k &= \v(X_k) \quad &y_k = \v(Y_k) \\
x &= \m{x_1\\x_2} \quad &y = \m{y_1\\y_2} \\
}$$
and [vectorize the equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) using Kronecker products to obtain
$$\eqalign{
{\cal K} &= \m{(I+A\otimes A)&B\otimes B\\C\otimes C&(I+D\otimes D)}\\
y &= {\cal K} x \\
}$$

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in the OP. I am aware of the kronecker-vec trick (in fact this is currently how I am solving the coupled matrix equation). The problem with this is that this is not practical for large matrices as the $\mathcal{K}$ matrix becomes $N^2 \times N^2$ which is scales horribly in memory for $N > 100$.

This is why I am looking for a way to rewrite the coupled matrix equation as another matrix equation (which only uses $N \times N$ matrices) and not a matrix-vector equation. I won't be accepting this answer since it doesn't explicitly answer the question in the OP.